# Multiple UIImage view

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I currently have an image set into my UIImageView the following way:

```
art_image.image = UIImage(named:(artworkPin.title!))
```

where art_image is the image View and **artworkPin.title** refers to the name of the image. However, I want to add a second image to the UIImageView if it exists I thought of programming it as

```
       art_image.image = UIImage(named:(artworkPin.title + "1")?)
```

would this work? In this case I would name a second image the name of the first image but with a '1' on the end. Example: 'Photo.jpeg' and 'Photo1.jpeg' would both be in the image view **if** Photo1.jpeg existed.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you can only show 1 image inside the imageivew at a time, so if you have the lines as follows:

```
art_image.image = UIImage(named:(artworkPin.title!))
art_image.image = UIImage(named:(artworkPin.title! + "1")?)
```

art_image would consist only of Photo1 provided such an image exists and that the artworkPin.title unwrapped is also not nil otherwise you could see some different results.

if you do want to add multiple images to an image view for the purpose of animation, you need to use the **animationImages** property of UIImageView which takes an array of UIImages for example

```
art_image.animationImages = [UIImage.init(named:"Photo")!, 
                             UIImage.init(named:"Photo1")!]
```

Hope this helps

**EDIT**

```
var imagesListArray = [UIImage]()

for position in 1...5
{
   if let image = UIImage.init(named: ("Photo\(position)"))
   {
      imagesListArray.append(image)
   }
}

art_image.animationImages = imagesListArray
art_image.animationDuration = 3.0
art_image.startAnimating()
```

This would be a safer a way to add the images so it will ONLY add an image if it is not nil and adds Photo1, Photo2 ..... Photo5

With regards to your other questions:

If you want the user to be able to

*What do you mean by animation?*
I have added two more lines of code, and it gives this result:

```
art_image.animationDuration = 1.0
art_image.startAnimating()
```

It will give you something like this: 
[image: animating between Photo1, Photo2, Photo3]

If you want the user to swipe, then you need to make some changes such as:
using a scrollview, collectionview for example is the easiest or using a gesture recognizer on swipe you need to change the image

**EDIT**

[image: image changes on button tap]

Have a look at this example. Imagine each button is your annotation so when I tap it, the image changes.

I have 3 images named Photo11.png, Photo21.png and Photo31.png and this is my code inside the button handler

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    if let image = UIImage.init(named: sender.currentTitle!+"1")
    {
            art_image.image = image
    }
}
```

As you can see I am setting the image with the title of my button + "1" as so it displays either Photo11.png or Photo21.png etc

Comment: What do you mean by animation? I want it to be so the user can slide the image to show the second image. Also, can I change the '!' optional to '?' so that it will only add it if it exists?

Comment: how do I change this to fit my code though? I cannot have it as "Photo\(position)" as artwork.title changes depending on which artwork is picked.

Comment: would it be: `if let image = UIImage.init(named: (artworkPin.title! + \ ("position"))` ?

Comment: @T.Kearsley If you want the user to slide to view another image, just a simple `UIImageView` is not enough. You need to use `UIPageView`.

Comment: Ok If I want it to animate what do I need to do

Comment: would you also be able to add the code for the page view? No worries if you can't

Comment: @T.Kearsley - can you explain a little bit about how your app functions ? How does artworkPin.title change ? Does the user type the image name or something else ? You mention the user needs to slide to reach the next image but also say the image comes from artworkPin.title so the user experience is not so clear to me. Maybe just tell me what do you need to happen in your app.

Comment: My app uses MapKit, each annotation is named and has a info button that links to a picture and description about the pin. Based on the name of the annotation the image and description is picked from the assets folder and the UIImage view is set as that image.

Comment: @T.Kearsley - I added some code to answer, hope this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar task myself once. What I did was, I created a `UIScrollView` with the frame of the `UIImageView` and its `contentSize` would be `imageView.frame.size.width * numberOfImages`.

```
let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: view.bounds)
view.addSubview(scrollView)

scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollView.bounds.size.width * CGFloat(numberOfImages), height: scrollView.bounds.size.height))

for i in 0...<numberOfImages.count-1 {
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: scrollView.bounds.size.width * CGFloat(i), y: scrollView.bounds.origin.y, width: scrollView.bounds.size.width, height: scrollView.bounds.size.height))
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "artwork" + "\(i)")
    scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
}
```

You can animate it to scroll with a `Timer` if you want.

```
scrollView.setContentOffset(scrollPoint, animated: true)
```